# How can I obtain a scrollable tbody section into an HTML table?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

I have the following problem trying to make scrollable the **tbody** section of an HTML table.

So for example I have this simple HTML table:

```
<table border="1" class="scrollableTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="14.2%">Codice RM</th>
            <th width="14.2%">Autore Firma</th>
            <th width="14.2%">Data Firma</th>
            <th width="14.2%">Acq Riserva</th>
            <th width="14.2%">Consegna Finale</th>
            <th width="14.2%">Descrizione RM</th>
            <th width="14.2%">Imponibile</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
         <tr class="even" id="rmRow">
             <td width="14.2%">0001</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">00000000</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">19/09</td>
             <td width="14.2%">57.0</td>
          </tr>

         <tr class="even" id="rmRow">
             <td width="14.2%">0002</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">00000000</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">19/09</td>
             <td width="14.2%">57.0</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="even" id="rmRow">
             <td width="14.2%">0003</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">00000000</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">19/09</td>
             <td width="14.2%">57.0</td>
          </tr>

         <tr class="even" id="rmRow">
             <td width="14.2%">0004</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">00000000</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">19/09</td>
             <td width="14.2%">57.0</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="even" id="rmRow">
             <td width="14.2%">0005</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">00000000</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">19/09</td>
             <td width="14.2%">57.0</td>
          </tr>

         <tr class="even" id="rmRow">
             <td width="14.2%">0006</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">00000000</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">bla</td>
             <td width="14.2%">19/09</td>
             <td width="14.2%">57.0</td>
          </tr>

       </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see in the **tbody** section there are some rows. These rows could be many so I want that this section have a specific heightand that it is scrollable (so I can see all the rows).

So I add these CSS settings trying to do it:

1. First I set the **tbody** section as a block so I can set an height to it.
2. Then I set an height to the **tbody** section.
3. Finally I set the verical overflow as scroll to make scrollable my **tbody** section.

This is my CSS code:

```
tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But this is what I obtain:

**JSFiddle link**: http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/4v1xnwzo/2/

**HTML result**: http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/4v1xnwzo/2/embedded/result/

As you can see the final result is pretty horrible and the **tbody columns** don't match wuth the **thead columns**.

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: I tried messing with your code but couldn't figure it out. Would it be fine to use 2 tables. One that is fixed and one that has overflow like this http://jsfiddle.net/xLuyxvfz/1/?

Comment: @AndrewH I alredy know this solution. I am asking if exist a more elegant solution using only one table

Comment: It is possible with proper td width calculated. Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4v1xnwzo/5/)

Answer (score 1):

The cells in your `tbody` will only line up with the cells in the `thead` if it has `display: table-row-group;`. Thus we can't set a height on the `tbody`, so we have to find a workaround.

The `table` itself can have `overflow-y: scroll;`, which gives us the scrolling for the rows in `tbody`, but unfortunately also includes scrolling the `thead`. You can avoid this behaviour by fixed positioning `thead`. and manipulating the way its displayed a little to make it look static at the top of the table while the rest of the table scrolls.

I've [updated your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4v1xnwzo/8/) with the css below:

```
tbody {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

table {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
thead {
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-right: 25px;
    display: table-row-group;
}
th, td {
    width: 80px;
}
```